# Most recent has_one from a has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship, has-many

I have a company model with a key (domain). I have a contact model which also has a domain.

I have successfully setup a has_many relationship between these two.

```
has_many :contacts, class_name: 'Contact', primary_key: 'domain', foreign_key: 'domain'
```

Each contact has a `date` field on it. I'd like a relationship which gets me the most recent contact (by `date`) from the `contacts` relationship.

Is this possible?

I'm aware I could do something like:

```
def most_recent_contact
  contacts.order('date desc null last').first
end
```

Is this the best way? Is it the *rails* way? Open to suggestions.

Comment: do you mean - most recent contact for any x `company` from the contacts relationship?

Comment: yes. So for a given company, the set of contacts will be for that company (eg all those at xyz.com).

Answer (score 2):

Well, this seems to be ONE way, but it doesn't "reuse" the relationship (it repeats it)...

```
has_many :contacts, class_name: 'Contact', primary_key: 'domain', foreign_key: 'domain'
has_one  :most_recent_contact, -> { order date:  :desc }, class_name: 'Contact', primary_key: 'domain', foreign_key: 'domain'
```

Comment: Both of your approach are good enough ways to fetch this information. I really liked this one! Your resultant db-query will remain the same :)

Comment: Thanks. It niggles me that I cant teach it to use the has_many as that already defined the class, primary and foreign keys.

Comment: If you use this in more complicated querry, You may lose orderrng.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Karger came in https://www.salsify.com/blog/engineering/most-recent-by-group-in-rails with (IMHO) best and solid solution.

Simply said:

1. Create scope `Contact.most_recent_by_domain` (with specific SQL)
2. Merge that scope into `has_one  :most_recent_contact, -> { merge(Contact.most_recent_by_domain) }, class_name: 'Contact', primary_key: 'domain', foreign_key: 'domain'`