# In Ruby on Rails, how can I create a has_many relation for "previous records"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

Let's say I have a `User` model and a `Contact` model. And I have the following relations in the `user.rb` class:

```
has_many :contacts
has_one :most_recent_contact, -> { order(created_at: :desc }
```

I saw this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38647605/1218280 and I got thinking:

**What if I wanted to add a `has_many :previous_contacts` relationship?**

So if the user had 5 contacts, the `has_many :contacts` would return an array of all 5, the `has_one :most_recent_contact` would return a single contact, and `has_many :previous_contacts` would return an array of 4 contacts.

Granted, I can do this inefficiently with something like:

```
def previous_contacts
  contacts - [most_recent_contact]
end
```

But I'm wondering if I could accomplish the same thing with a `has_many` relation, which reads better (to me)

Thoughts?

Comment: It is not recommended. Because if you do `has_many :previous_contacts`, the database grows. But I would love to hear more thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `offset` to skip the first record:

```
has_many :previous_contacts, -> { order(created_at: :desc).offset(1) } ...
```